# Prove that the centre of a group is $\mathbb{Z}_{r}$

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups, representation-theory, semidirect-product

I was wondering if anyone could give me some help on the following problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Let $G$ be a group of order $r^3$ with $r$ an odd prime. Assume $G$ is non-abelian and has exponent $r$. Then $G=N:H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{r}^{2}:\mathbb{Z}_{r}$, where $:$ denotes the semi-direct product. Let $F=GF(p)$ and assume that $r$ divides $p-1$. Prove that $Z(G)=\mathbb{Z}_{r}$ where $Z(G)$ denotes the centre of $G$.

What I have so far is that as the centre is a normal subgroup, so must have order $1$,$r$,$r^{2}$ or $r^{3}$. Clearly it can't have order $r^{3}$ otherwise $G$ would be abelian. Any suggestions from here?

Comment: Hint: $p$-groups have non-trivial center, and the quotient by the center is never cyclic.

Comment: What does the field $F$ have to do with the question?

Comment: My apologies it's for a later part! If I prove this, I can then deduce that there is an irreducible faithful $FG$-module. Which I have to prove has dimension greater than or equal to $2$. I then have to prove that it is non-homogeneous for $\mathbb{Z}_{r}^{2}$ and then use Clifford's Theorem to find what the $FG$-module is. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft - OK so it can't have order 1 as p-groups have non-trivial centre. But how do I use that $G/Z(G)$ isn't cyclic to prove that $Z(G)=\mathbb{Z}_{r}$ i.e. has order $r$?